# Extracting name values from records having overlapping dates

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause, date-range

I have a table containing areas whose size changes over time. The timeframe (in years) for which an area size is valid is stored in the columns "*VALID_FROM*" and "*VALID_UNTIL*". The timeframes for one area must not overlap. I want to create a query with which I can check if someone has entered overlapping timeframes.

In the example table the validity timeframes from area1 do overlap.

Table "**areas**":

| NAME | SIZE | VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area1 | 55 | 1990 | **2005** |
| area1 | 40 | **2000** | 2009 |
| area1 | 45 | 2010 | 2099 |
| area2 | 79 | 1990 | 2099 |
| area3 | 33 | 1990 | 1999 |
| area3 | 37 | 2000 | 2009 |

Note that end dates are inclusive e.g. there is no gap in the two dates for area3.

It would be sufficient to have a result like this:

| NAME | REMARK |
| --- | --- |
| area1 | 'timeframes overlap!' |

My problem is that an area may occure n times in the table, I dont know how to compare the "*VALID_FROM*" and "*VALID_UNTIL*" columns if there could be an arbitrary number of rows for one area.

So far I got as far as reducing the table to those rows which occur more than once.

```
WITH duplicats AS (
    SELECT `NAME`
    FROM `areas`
    GROUP BY `NAME`
    HAVING COUNT(`NAME`) > 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM       `areas`
INNER JOIN `duplicats`
        ON `areas`.`NAME` = `duplicats`.`NAME`
```

Comment: Simply do a self join.

Comment: Is valid until date inclusive or exclusive? I mean can you have `2000-2005, 2005-2010` or `2000-2005, 2006-2010`?

Comment: They are exclusive, you cannot have 2000-2005, 2005-2010. It should be 2000-2004, 2005-2010

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8.x, you could subtract the previous `valid_until` value from the  `valid_from` value, if there is a negative difference then there is an overlap.

```
select NAME, 'timeframes overlap!' AS Remark
from
(
  select *,
    VALID_FROM - lag(VALID_UNTIL) over (partition by NAME order by VALID_FROM) df
  from areas
) t
group by NAME
having sum(df <= 0) > 0
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PqmHc7ms)

Comment: Another way to look at it is if lag(valid_until) >= valid_from from then you have an overlap. This of course needs MySQL 8 or later.

Comment: @SalmanA, yes, I am supposing MySQL 8 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by self join your tables :

```
select s1.*
from mytable s1
inner join mytable s2 on (
    s1.VALID_FROM between s2.VALID_FROM and s2.VALID_UNTIL
    OR
    s1.VALID_UNTIL between s2.VALID_FROM and s2.VALID_UNTIL
    OR
    s2.VALID_FROM between s1.VALID_FROM and s1.VALID_UNTIL
) and s1.NAME = s2.NAME and s1.VALID_FROM <> s2.VALID_FROM and s1.VALID_UNTIL <> s2.VALID_UNTIL
```

Result :

```
NAME    SIZE    VALID_FROM  VALID_UNTIL
area1   40      2000        2009
area1   55      1990        2005
```

Or if you want result grouped by area then :

```
select s1.NAME, group_concat(DISTINCT concat(s1.VALID_FROM,'-', s1.VALID_UNTIL)) as REMARK
from mytable s1
inner join mytable s2 on (
    s1.VALID_FROM between s2.VALID_FROM and s2.VALID_UNTIL
    OR
    s1.VALID_UNTIL between s2.VALID_FROM and s2.VALID_UNTIL
    OR
    s2.VALID_FROM between s1.VALID_FROM and s1.VALID_UNTIL
) and s1.NAME = s2.NAME and s1.VALID_FROM <> s2.VALID_FROM and s1.VALID_UNTIL <> s2.VALID_UNTIL
group by s1.NAME
```

Result :

```
NAME    REMARK
area1   1990-2005,2000-2009
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tMR1Zn3s)

Comment: No, this logic is too complicated and possibly wrong. You need just two tests to check overlap.

Comment: Not sure it is complicated ! any test case that can get wrong results ?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2fab/3 fails test #3

Comment: there is no fails, You have executed the first query that get overlaps times, try the second one : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2fab/7

Comment: `1990, 1999` should overlap `1990, 1999`. Besides, if you look at my answer (or google how to check overlap) you'll find that you just need to test two conditions... your testing 6.

Comment: they are indeed overlaped http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ab7cb/1

Answer (score 1):

To test for overlaps you would simply:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
    select *
    from t as x
    where x.id <> t.id -- pri. key check is needed to avoid comparing row with itself
    and x.name = t.name
    and t.valid_until >= x.valid_from
    and t.valid_from  <= x.valid_until
)
```

The two from-until date comparisons are sufficient to find all kind of overlaps. The answer assumes until date is inclusive.

Comment: Why are you considering e.g. 2000-2009, 2009-2012 as overlapping?

Comment: @lemon guessing from the data in OP they are overlapping. Area 3 ends with 1999 and starts with 2000.

Comment: They're not overlapping, otherwise area3 would be in the output, right?

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` a calendar table or cte. Do a `GROUP BY` and use `HAVING` to find years having two (or more) rows with the same area.

```
with recursive years (y) as
    (select min(valid_from) from areas
     union all
     select y + 1 from years
     where y <= (select max(valid_until) from areas)
    )
select distinct a.name
from areas a
join years on y between valid_from and valid_until
group by a.name, y
having count(*) > 1;
```